# Publishing update of the app to App store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have to push an update of app (I got the source code from the client and done some minor changes). I asked client for Apple dev login credentials but he is not willing to give me(it's obvious) however he asked me what info do I need from him. I know that I have to use the same distribution profile for creating the IPA. What else do I need from him in order to build the binary? **e.g.** Distribution Key in Keychain access etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your client don't want to provide Apple dev login credentials so it's not possible form your side. Because when you will going to submit your app you need to login to `iTunes Connect`.

[image]

So better I'll suggest you to submit you code to client and give him instructions (from installing xCode to uploading app) to upload your app as a new version.

Comment: Thank you! see my edited question. First version was published by someone else and now I am going to do the update so what do I need from client (profile, keys etc)?